# converting resultset to RDF/XML in Jena

Tags: java, xml, rdf, jena

I'm trying to convert a `resultset` in XML/RDF format but with this code:

```
ResultSet result = rmParliament.selectQuery(select);
System.out.println(ResultSetFormatter.asText(result));
ResultSetFormatter.outputAsRDF(System.out, "RDF/XML", result);
```

The second line of the code is to verify the correct behaviour of the query (it works!), but I get in the console the following output:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rs="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#" > 
 <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A0">
    <rs:size rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int">0</rs:size>
    <rs:resultVariable>value</rs:resultVariable>
    <rs:resultVariable>property</rs:resultVariable>
    <rs:resultVariable>name</rs:resultVariable>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#ResultSet"/>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Is doesn't contain my data, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your print debugging actually consumes all the results, leaving the `ResultSet` at the end. There are no more results available when you try to output it as RDF/XML.

You can fix it by making the `ResultSet` [rewindable](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetFactory.html#makeRewindable(com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet)):

```
ResultSetRewindable result =
    ResultSetFactory.makeRewindable( rmParliament.selectQuery(select) );
System.out.println(ResultSetFormatter.asText(result));
result.reset(); // back to the start
ResultSetFormatter.outputAsRDF(System.out, "RDF/XML", result);
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just removed the debugging print...and now it works.