# jena ResultSetFormatter "asText" doesnt give the same results as "OUT"

Tags: java, sparql, resultset, jena

I make a query to my SPARQL endpoint from jena, all good.

I used to print the returning dataset as this:

ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);

where results is from `org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;`

and this is what I get :

[image]

However, when i say this

System.out.println(ResultSetFormatter.asText(results));

I get just the columns **without the data**, as you see here:

[image]

What is going on guys please?

(i need to have the results as string because I make it the body for HTTP response)

Comment: Did you do one *after* the other?  Or *instead* of the other? You can only get the results from the result set once.  If that's the problem here, then this is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27168750/1281433.

Comment: I also think that this was done after it was already iterated over the resultset in maybe some other loop before. The Jena `ResultSet` is an iterator, you can check the documentation for it. If you need it again, as far as I remember there is something to convert it into a `ResultSetRewindable`, which is something on that you can navigate multiple times and in both directions.

Comment: @aksw yes, the question I linked to shows an example of the conversion to a rewindable result set.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes exactly when i removed the first print, the other one works, thanks a lot.